# How to switch Off / Turn Off Android Tablet through coding?

Tags: java, hardware, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android

I am having Micromax Fun Book with Android Version 4.0.3 and I want to Turn Off that tablet through my android code.

Actually I want to turn off the tablet as soon as my application exits.
May be I need some hardware Permission. I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can reboot the device using PowerManager API. You may need to have REBOOT permission in your manifest though.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot(java.lang.String)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT

Answer (score 1):

Android will not allow switching off a device through code, maybe later some rooted devices will allow this.

But we can give them a dialog, as below, to turn off the device:

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", true);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

All those code will work only on Rooted Device, otherwise not.